# ¿Porque no me imprime linea a linea?

Tags: linux, script

tengo el siguiente código y quiero que me imprima una linea , posteriormente que escriba siguiente linea y que despues me muestre la siguiente linea , sin embargo me muestra todos las lineas seguidas y finalmente me muestra el mensaje de siguiente linea.He probado a quitarle las comillas dobles en la variable "$gol" del for pero al quitarle las comillas dobles me va cogiendo un elemento de la linea y no la linea entera .

```
#!/bin/bash

gol=$(sudo lastb | awk '{print $1,$4,$5}' | sort | uniq -c | tr -s ' ')

for linea in "$gol"

do

    echo "$linea"
    echo"siguiente linea"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que esta tomando todo como un solo bloque.
Si cambiamos el **IFS** indicando que el separador debe ser el salto de linea e iteramos por **${gol}** para que genere el arreglo dividiendo por el **IFS** debemos obtener lo que necesitas:

```
#!/bin/bash

gol=$(sudo lastb | awk '{print $1,$4,$5}' | sort | uniq -c | tr -s ' ')

# indicamos que separe por saltos de linea
IFS=$'\n'

for linea in ${gol}
do

    echo "$linea"
    echo "siguiente linea"
done
```